# Apache configure file: how to edit it

Tags: apache2, php, apache2.4, xdebug

I need to edit the Apache configure file because I wish to set the debugger port in my VirtualHost section as it says below. How can I do it? I searched in Google but it is not clear for me what I should do.

```
php_value xdebug.remote_port 9009
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VirtualHost files are located at:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/
```

If you are still using the default VirtualHost file, you will need to edit

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/default.conf
```

If the previous file was not available, it might be called

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

The line should be added anywhere between the two tags

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
</VirtualHost>
```

But not inside the `<Directory>` tags.

The safest place to put it is directly before the closing of the `</VirtualHost>` tag.

---

Don't forget to restart/reload apache after editing the file

```
sudo apache2ctl restart
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Dan. In which part of default.conf should I place the line you see in my question?

Comment: @pablofiumara Edited the info into the post